# Fetching first character from a word and replace with * based on any condition

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I need to fetch first char of contact names (includes all language) and replace chars which don't satisfy range of char-set for selected language.

For example:- My table will be having English contacts and Chinese contacts, now if I select Chinese language then my query should give me all the first chars from the names but for English contact it should return '*'.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a good lead for you to get going](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Plenty of useful information there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the information but it will not help to me at this time.

Comment: Except this is the only help anyone can offer here. Your question boils down to "I don't know how to do this". Well, reading a C++ book is the only way to learn how to do this. You can't really expect someone on stackoverflow.com to write an entire program like that, and show it here. If there's a specific C++ question, or a problem, then it should be asked directly using a [mcve].

Comment: Give an example of what you want.

Comment: Something like this 

"SELECT (substr(FirstName, 1, 1)), unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))),
       CASE WHEN ( 90 > (unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))) > 65) AND (unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))) < 90))
       THEN (substr(FirstName, 1, 1))
       ELSE '#'
       END AS Indx
FROM Emp " @DmytroDadyka

Comment: @srb_programming. Add this to you quation (edit)

Comment: How do you track what language a contact is in?

Comment: @Shawn I would check its Unicode of contact's first char.

Comment: @Shawn : You may check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233968.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, I have created below query to achieve desired output, Unicode values are getting compared and assigned to '#' though it needs some improvement.

For English language:-

"SELECT (substr(FirstName, 1, 1)), unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))), CASE WHEN ( 90 > (unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))) > 65) AND (unicode((substr(FirstName, 1, 1))) < 90)) THEN (substr(FirstName, 1, 1)) ELSE '#' END AS Indx FROM Emp "

Similarly will be achieved for other languages based on their Unicode range of character set. 
Thanks everyone for your response. :)